# Joining queries in access not working

Tags: microsoft-access, sql

I have 3 tables 
Employees(EmpID, FN, LN)
Required Trainings(TrainingID, TrainingName)
Completed Trainings(CompletedID, EmployeeName (lookup field from Employee), TrainingName (lookup field from Required Trainings), Completed Date)

I then created queries to display all the information within the tables

```
SELECT CaregiverInformation.CaregiverID, CaregiverInformation.FirstName, CaregiverInformation.LastName
FROM CaregiverInformation;

SELECT CaregiverCompletedTraining.TrainingRecordID, CaregiverCompletedTraining.Caregiver, CaregiverCompletedTraining.Training, CaregiverCompletedTraining.CompletedDate, CaregiverCompletedTraining.ExpiredDate, IIf(Date()>=[ExpiredDate],"Expired","Current") AS IsExpired
FROM CaregiverCompletedTraining;

SELECT RequiredTrainings.TrainingID, RequiredTrainings.TrainingName, RequiredTrainings.Required
FROM RequiredTrainings;
```

If an employee takes a training it is tracked in the completed trainings table. I need to create a query that will show all the trainings listed within the required trainings for all employees in the employee table regardless if they are in the completed training table. However, if it is in the completed training table i want it to list the date the training was taken.

I am able to get a query to list all the employees with all the trainings with the following SQL code

```
SELECT qry_CaregiverInformation.CaregiverID, qry_CaregiverInformation.FirstName, qry_CaregiverInformation.LastName, qry_RequiredTrainings.TrainingName
FROM qry_CaregiverInformation, qry_CompletedTrainings, qry_RequiredTrainings
WHERE (((qry_CaregiverInformation.CaregiverID) Like "*") AND ((qry_RequiredTrainings.TrainingName) Like "*"));
```

However I cannot get the completed information to work properly. I've tried a union and the amount of columns do not match. If I add null columns in my SQL I get a data mismatch error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I always find it helpful to have some test sample SQL data and queries you have trouble with on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or some similar online tool and to post a link with your question there too so people can help with your actual data and be assured the results are what are expected. Just in case you cannot confirm otherwise, consider taking the time and getting that setup as such if you still don't get what you need and then [edit] and add a link to your data, etc. so people that can help can test.

Answer (score 0):

it's just a simple left join:

```
select * 
from CaregiverInformation i 
left join RequiredTrainings r on r.CaregiverID = i.CaregiverID
left join CaregiverCompletedTraining c on c.TrainingRecordID = r.TrainingRecordID
```

if you want to limit i only if r exists, then use inner join there:

```
select * 
from CaregiverInformation i 
inner join RequiredTrainings r on r.CaregiverID = i.CaregiverID
left join CaregiverCompletedTraining c on c.TrainingRecordID = r.TrainingRecordID
```

read more about the differences between joins here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins